# Zend Gdata class: How to save Calendar item in specific calendar

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

How do I select the calendar to use when creating events using the Zend Gdata library. It's pretty easy to create an event in the default calendar (http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#CreatingEvents)

But I do not understand how I can create an entry in another calendar. Any idea's?

Comment: Okay, found it myself... the insertEvent($event, $link) method accepts a second parameter in which you can put the link to the calendar in which you would like to save the event. Use the 'link' parameter that can be found in the Zend_Gdata_Calendar_ListFeed class

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so others who search for it can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it myself... the insertEvent($event, $link) method accepts a second parameter in which you can put the link to the calendar in which you would like to save the event. Use the 'link' parameter that can be found in the Zend_Gdata_Calendar_ListFeed class